# onApprove and onDeny not triggered in modal - semantic ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, semantics

When I show my modal, the onApprove event is called automatically. How can I stop this?
My code is as below

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="content">
       <a href="#" ng-click="showItemPanel()">Deactivate Account</a>
       <div id='showItemModal' class='ui modal'>
       <i class="close icon"></i>
       <div class="header">
         Deactivate User
       </div>
       <div class="content">
       <form class="ui form" name="ItemModalForm">
          <div class="field">
            You want to go to shopping?                 
          </div>
       </form>
       </div>
       <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui tiny button">Cancel</div>
        <div class="ui tiny green button" ng-click="showItems()">De-Activate</div>
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.showItemPanel= function() {
            var modalElem= $('#showItemModal').modal('setting', {
            closable  : false,
            onDeny    : function(){
              window.alert('Wait not yet!');
              return false;
            },
            onApprove : itemPanelOpen()
            });
          modalElem.modal('show');           
        }
        function itemPanelOpen()
        {
            console.log(user.name + " can now shop!");
        }
```

For me, as soon as showItemPanel function is called, itemPanelOpen function is also getting call automatically. Please let me know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem today and find out the definition of buttons should be

```
<div class="actions">
        <div class="ui tiny button deny">Cancel</div>
        <div class="ui tiny green button approve">De-Activate</div>
</div>
```

With the 'approve' in button's class attribute, the onApprove and onDeny event can work.

You can find document of Semantic UI of modal [DOM selector](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/settings):

```
selector    : {
  close    : '.close, .actions .button',
  approve  : '.actions .positive, .actions .approve, .actions .ok',
  deny     : '.actions .negative, .actions .deny, .actions .cancel'
}
```

I had spend a couple of hours on figuring out on event not triggered and feel the document is not very well written here.

Answer (score 4):

```
onApprove : itemPanelOpen()
```

The parentheses at the end means you want to call the function, and set `onApprove` to whatever `itemPanelOpen()` evaluates to.

Since you just want to reference the function, leave out the parentheses:

```
onApprove: itemPanelOpen
```

This is because, in javascript, functions are first class objects. You can read more about them in [Functions and function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) at Mozilla Developer Network.

Comment: I have changed my code like below. Now I found that onApprove is not even triggered. Should I manually like the 'CANCEL' and 'DEACTIVATE' button to the functions in the controller?

Comment: $scope.showItemPanel= function() {
            var modalElem= $('#showItemModal').modal('setting', {
            closable  : false,
            onDeny    : function(){
              window.alert('Wait not yet!');
              return false;
            },
            onApprove :  function(){
                console.log("On approve called");
            }
            });
          modalElem.modal('show');           
        }
        function itemPanelOpen()
        {
            console.log(user.name + " can now shop!");
        }

Comment: What is the library you are using for modal dialogs? Does it support an `onApprove` callback/

Comment: i hav just called semantic ui library folder fully in my angular js project

Comment: To be more specific i have added semantic.css from packaged folder. I am not using angular bootstrap ui.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you are still looking for answer, but you need to add the "positive" or "approve" or "ok" class to your button. According to the [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#/examples): "Modals will automatically tie approve deny callbacks to any positive/approve, negative/deny or ok/cancel buttons."

```
 <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui tiny button cancel">Cancel</div>
    <div class="ui tiny green button ok" ng-click="showItems()">De-Activate</div>
 </div>
```

Probably any of the following

> positive / approve / ok

will work.

Answer (score 1):

don't add word 'settngs'

```
$('.mini.modal.delete').modal({
    onApprove : function(){alert("delete")}
}).modal('show');
```